# Proper usage of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let's consider the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{b_n}. \tag{1}$$

Of course, in general, the following statement is false
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n}},$$
we can give an obvious counterexample, i.e.
$$e = \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n} \bigg)^{n} \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n} \bigg)^{\lim_{n\to\infty} n} = 1.$$

However there are plenty other examples which can be solved using $(1)$ and the result is correct. Is it enough to assume that $(1)$ holds if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$, where $a, b \neq 0$ and $a, b$ are finite?

Let's consider one more example
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{n+4}{n+3}\bigg)^{5-2n}.$$
After several simple transformations we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{n+4}{n+3}\bigg)^{5-2n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigg(\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n+3}\bigg)^{n+3}\Bigg)^{\frac{5-2n}{n+3}}.$$

Let
$$a_n = \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n+3}\bigg)^{n+3}, \qquad b_n = \frac{5-2n}{n+3}.$$
Of course
$$a_n \to e, \qquad b_n \to -2,$$
due to the fact that both limits differ from zero and are finite we conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{n+4}{n+3}\bigg)^{5-2n} = e^{-2}.$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell this should hold as long as all the limits exist (and $a$ is a posivie real number, $b$ a real number). This should follow by taking logs and then using standard limit rules and sequential continuity. Please let me know if that is incorrect.

Comment: @Fishbane, thanks for the tip. I will try to prove that statement.

Comment: It's confusing to "bind" the variable $n$ in a context where it is already bound.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on what Fishbane pointed out, we have that since $\log$ is a continuous function on $(0, \infty)$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log(x_n) = \log(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n)$ if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n > 0$. Then if $a_n \rightarrow a$ where $a \neq 0$, then
$$
\begin{align*} 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log(a_n^{b_n}) &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n \log(a_n) \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n \ \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log(a_n) \\
&= b \ \cdot \log(a). 
\end{align*}
$$
Then since $e^x$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n^{b_n} &= e^{b \log a} \\
&= a^b.
\end{align*}
$$
Note that throughout we never needed that $b \neq 0$; from the argument here we see that if $b = 0$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n^{b_n} = 1$. Hope this helps! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you! That's a clear explanation. By the way do you have any idea how to prove that statement without using the $\log$ function? Just the sequences?

Comment: Well, we can see that $$|a_n^{b_n} - a_{n+1}^{b_{n+1}}| \leq |a_n^{b_n} - a_{n+1}^{b_n}| + |a_{n+1}^{b_n} - a_{n+1}^{b_{n+1}}|.$$ So if you can show that both of the things on the right converge to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, then we get that the sequence is Cauchy, and therefore convergent. We can see more easily that $|a_{n+1}^{b_n} - a_{n+1}^{b_{n+1}}|$ converges to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, but showing that $|a_n^{b_n} - a_{n+1}^{b_n}|$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity is more tricky